# Ionic's navigation bar obstructs iframe

Tags: android, cordova, iframe, ionic-framework

I write this question because the answers to the other very similar ones weren't helpful:

- [Show a website inside an ionic tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799682/show-a-website-inside-an-ionic-tab)
- [How to make a container fill whole screen below the navigation bar in Ionic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980711/how-to-make-a-container-fill-whole-screen-below-the-navigation-bar-in-ionic)

So, the problem is, I have a page in an Ionic app that only has the navigation bar and an iframe, but when you export it to a device the navigation bar takes space in front of the iframe, something that doesn't happen when running the app with **ionic serve --lab**.

How do I fix this?

The code is like this:

```
<ion-view view-title="Detalles de mensaje" class="detallesWV-page">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon-round" ng-click="openPopover($event)">
    </button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>

  <ion-content scroll="false">
    <div id="contenido" style="top:10px;">
      <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="http://cnn.com"></iframe>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding class="has-header" on ion-content

Comment: Remove style "top:10px" from the div. Here is a plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/Y8raxGlCfI91ox5jduHf?p=preview

Comment: I already did, doesn't work. Then I removed the div, didn't work either.